# UTF-16 decoding fails when reading from csv

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to read a csv that contains some UTF-16 strings. When I print these string as extracted from the csv they don't decode to cyrillic/japanese/whatever as they should, instead just print the encoded utf-16. Yet when I copy/paste the strings and print them directly, there's no problem.

```
data = pd.read_csv('stuff.csv')
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    print('\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430')
    print(row[1])
```

outputs:

```
Украина
\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430
```

what am I missing? Note that some of the CSV is ascii so I can't just set encoding to utf-16 for the csv.

Edit: I'm trying to conditionally decode the strings where utf-16 is detected. Tried both the string taken from the csv and the copy/pasted string:

```
print(bytearray(row[1].encode()).decode('utf-16'))
print(b'\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430'.decode('utf-16'))
```

For some reason it decodes to chinese characters:

```
畜㐰㌲畜㐰愳畜㐰〴畜㐰〳畜㐰㠳畜㐰搳畜㐰〳
畜㐰㌲畜㐰愳畜㐰〴畜㐰〳畜㐰㠳畜㐰搳畜㐰〳
```

Comment: Does your file actually contain Unicode characters, or does it contain the Unicode escapes ("\u0423\u043a...")?  Remember, the "\u" escapes are only recognized by the Python interpreter in string constants.  They don't work when reading from files.

Comment: is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Sure.  The `ast` module gives you access to Python's actual syntax parser. `from ast import literal_eval` / `print(literal_eval('"'+row[1]+'"'))`.  Note that I have to add quote marks to make it look like a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually have `\u` escapes in the file, you can use the Python `ast` module to get access to the interpreter's actual parser:

```
from ast import literal_eval
...
    print(literal_eval('"'+row[1]+'"'))
```

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
has an `encoding` argument.

Try `data = pd.read_csv('stuff.csv', encoding='utf-16')`

Comment: does this require the entire csv to be utf-16? Because I'm getting a UnicodeDecodeError and only some of the csv is utf-16, most of it is ascii.

Comment: Yes, most programs would expect a file to follow a consistent encoding. If you have [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) available, try running `file stuff.csv` to see what you get.

Comment: it just says "CSV text"

Comment: Well, then soultion would depent on your usecase. If this a one-off task and you can easily identify the UTF-16 rows you can split the CSV into two different files.

If its a large file and you have little control over it you can try reading the file twice and keeping track of the rows you successfully parsed using UTF-16 encoding. You can then later merge the two dataframes. You can take a look at the `encoding_errors` and `on_bad_lines` arguments of `read_csv`.

Comment: I'm trying to just decode the utf-16 strings as I encounter them... it's not going well, see the edit I made